# Does the bar in $\bar{\mathbb{R}}=\{-\infty,\infty \}\bigcup\mathbb{R}$ mean closure of the reals?

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

Does the bar in $\bar{\mathbb{R}}=\{-\infty,\infty \}\bigcup\mathbb{R}$ mean closure of the reals? Where Closure is defined as the union of the set and all it's limit points? 
Certain sequences in $\mathbb{R}$ move towards infinity.

Comment: It's more about compactness than closure.

Comment: This is a situation where you should not try to over-interpret the notation. That bar is used *in analogy to* other uses of the bar, some of which are explained in the answers. But analogies aside, it means what it says: $\bar{\mathbb R}$ means $\{-\infty,\infty\} \cup \mathbb R$. In this regard, I am in more agreement with the deleted answer of @Niklas than with the other answers.

Answer (score 4):

It can be thought of as the completion of $(\mathbb R,<)$ as a lattice - it becomes a complete lattice when adding $-\infty$ and $\infty.$ This means that any subset of $\overline{\mathbb R}$ has both a supremum and infimum in $\overline{\mathbb R}.$

We can't really think of it as the topological closure of $\mathbb R,$ since the closure of a space $X$ is define only inside a space $Y$ for which $X\subseteq Y.$ In particular, for different $Y,$ $\overline{X}$ is defined differently.

Certainly it is convenient that, inside $Y=\overline{\mathbb R}$ the closure of $X=\mathbb R$ is the whole space $Y.$ But there are other such spaces with $\mathbb R\subset Y$ with $\overline{\mathbb R}=Y.$ They each have different purposes.

The most simple is $Y=X=\mathbb R.$ Here, $\overline X=Y$ just trivially.

For more useful examples: there is the one-point-compactification of the reals. This is the simplest "compactification" of the reals, via a process that can be extended to any space, but the resulting space is no longer ordered.

Or the real projective line (which is homeomorphic to the one-point compactification, but the same operation to $\mathbb R^n$ are not the same - the one-point compactification always adds one point, $\infty,$ while the real projective space $\mathbb RP^n$ adds a space of "points at infinity" which is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^{n-1}$ at infinity.)

Comment: I really like the interpretation of extended real numbers as a complete lattice. That's why we add 2 elements, infinity and minus infinity, and not just one as in complex numbers.

Comment: The lattic completion of $(\mathbb Q,<)$ is $\overline{\mathbb R},$  which is essentially the Dedekind cut approach to the construction of the reals, but, phrased like this, it makes the two infinities a more natural part of the definition. The Cauchy sequence definition of the reals is based on $\mathbb Q$ as a metric space. (This is also why the Cauchy sequence definition makes the operations $+$ and $\times$ more easily defined than in the Dedekind definition.) @Jakobian

Answer (score -3):

Yes, this is called the closure of $\mathbb{R}$, however it is only one specific way to make $\mathbb{R}$ closed.

Comment: To call this a "closure" of the real numbers will not be informative.  A common name for it would be the *extended real numbers*.

Comment: Yes I think I agree with @hardmath

Comment: While that is true, it's using the set notation bar above as the closure symbol. Naturally that's not the only way that you can close $\mathbb{R}$, but it is one way. Just because something has more than one name doesn't mean that one of them is wrong, it typically means that the concept is just important.

Comment: Closed in what? It’s being compactified, not closed

Comment: Closed int the sense of being a the union of an open set and its boundary points (depending on how you define that).